# NodeJS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on ajax call using ReactJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, reactjs, connection

I'm currently creating a app running NodeJS on the serverside and ReactJS on the clientside (combined with jQuery).

```
loadQuestionsFromServer: function() {
    if(this.state.request) this.state.request.abort();

    this.state.request = $.ajax({
        url: '/api/questions/',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(obj) {
            this.setState({ questions: obj });
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error('/api/questions', status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

An example of my ajax calls is shown above. It does execute successfully, but my console is still logging a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error which I can't seem to debug:

[image]

The ajax call reads a file and returns the content of this file:

```
var QUESTION_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '../public/questions.json');

router.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

    fs.readFile(QUESTION_FILE, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        res.json(JSON.parse(data));
    });
});
```

I've found several "solutions" on the internet:

- Using local IP adress instead of localhost
- `setHeaders Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (as shown in the code)
- Add `crossDomain: true` to the ajax call

But none of them seem to work.
The error doesn't occur on the first ajax call when the page loads, but does occur when triggering a ajax call later in the process (both POST and GET).
*Edit:* Also not every time an ajax call is triggered the error occurs. It seems like it only does occur when I'll trigger quickly after each other..